# Check all CheckBoxes in an ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a cleaner way to check/uncheck all CheckBoxes inside an ArrayList?

"al" is ArrayList<CheckBox>

```kotlin
al.forEach {
    it.isChecked = false
}
```

Comment: Nope that's the shortest and cleanest you gonna get. I mean how much shorter do you want ? Lol put it all into one line and remove white spaces haha 

Comment: Seems pretty clean to me. What do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a cleaner way I'm assuming you mean a function to check/uncheck all with one function, so you can create an extension function to do that

```
fun List<CheckBox>.checkAll(check: Boolean) {
    this.forEach { 
        it.isChecked = check
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
val checkBoxes = ArrayList<CheckBox>()
checkBoxes.checkAll(true)
checkBoxse.checkAll(false)
```